# writing a foreach statement to loop within a collection

Tags: c#

I have a function defined like this:

```
public static bool ComposeObjects(List<ObjectID> TheListOfIDs)
```

The definition of `ObjectID` looks like this:

```
public class ObjectID
{
    int ObjectID { get; set; }
    byte Var1 { get; set; }
}
```

This function `ComposeObjects` receives a collection of `ObjectID`s and I want to loop in this collection.

How do you write the for each statement?

So far I have

```
foreach (ObjectID in TheListOfIDs)
{
    // ...
}
```

Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to give a variable name:

```
foreach (ObjectID id in TheListOfIDs)
{
   // Just for example...
   int x = id.ObjectID;
   byte b = id.Var1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your having a syntax problem? What errors? What have you tried?

```
foreach (var oID in TheListOfIDs)
{
...
}
```